# How can I dump multiple postgres schemas using rake db:dump:schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Our postgres database has two schemas: a public schema and a metadata schema.  I need both schemas in my test database, but `rake db:schema:dump` only dumps the public schema.  If I add  `schema_search_path: "public, metadata"` to my database.yml file, it dumps both schemas, but the schema information is not there.

How can I dump both schemas to `db/schema.rb` so I can load them with `rake db:test:prepare`?

Comment: Reading the code, I don't think it is possible unless you dump in native format. For example, I see you can add a table_name_prefix, but that is global and would get added to all the tables. Like, you could try "ActiveRecord::Base.table_name_prefix='public.'", it might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the answer is to use a structure file instead of a schema file.

**Add this to application.rb**

```
# use a .sql structure instead of a schema.rb for the schema
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

**remove your schema.rb file**

This will now dump your database using structure (sql) intead of schema (rb) and it can be more expressive. However, it is now tied to your database vendor (not a big deal for us).

```
bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
```